# Anyone know how to increment and decrement at the same time and put the output side by side?

Tags: java, loops, increment, decrement

Write an application that will ask the user to input a number. Your program will then display a number that starts and ends based on the number you entered and on the right side to reverse the numbers you displayed on the left side.

Expected output:

```
Enter a number: 5
1 5
2 4
3 3
4 2
5 1
```

I tried making a hollow box with increasing and decreasing numbers and making the other codes a comment to try and make the expected output. But I still can't manage to do so.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < num; ++j) {
            if (i == 0) {
                System.out.print((j + 1) + " ");
            //} else if (i == num-1) {
                System.out.print((num - j) + " ");
            } else if (j == 0) {
                System.out.print((i + 1) + " ");
            //} else if (j == num-1) {
                System.out.print((num - i) + " ");
            //} else {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don’t need two loops, make only one with two pointers, one start from the beginning , and one from the end.

Comment: Hint: is there a mathematical relationship between the numbers counting up and counting down? Can you take advantage of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're thinking too hard (;->).  It's not so complicated.

Here's one possible way:

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\n");
    int i = 1;
    int j = num;
    while (i >= num) {
        System.out.println(i + " " + j);
        i++;
        j--;
    }
}
```

Here's another:

```
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[])
{
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    int num = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("\n");
    for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i) {
        System.out.println(i + " " + (num - i + 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this is homework, I’ll give guidance instead of code.

The left column looks easy to produce - a simple loop will do it.

Consider the relationship between the left and right numbers. Notice they always total 6, or more generally `n + 1`. This the right column can be calculated by subtracting `i` from `n + 1`, where `i` is the left column value.